# How do i know the language of post/page in wordpress using wpml?

Tags: wordpress, wpml

I am using wpml
by using this code i can get the id of post/page

```
$id = icl_object_id($course_id, 'page', false, ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE);
```

i want to know that how can i get the language type of post/page
i have tried WP_query but it was futile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the solution ,

```
$post_language_information = wpml_get_language_information(get_the_ID());
echo <pre>;
print_r($post_language_information );
echo </pre>;
```

output

```
Array
(
    [language_code] => zh-hant
    [locale] => zh_TW
    [text_direction] => 
    [display_name] => 繁體中文
    [native_name] => 繁體中文
    [different_language] => 
)
```